# Error during Windows Zabbix Agent2 compilation from sources

Tags: windows, go, compilation, zabbix

I am trying to build a plugin that is destined to work specifically on Windows systems.
So as a starting point I wanted to rebuild the agent from sources before extending it with my code but while following the guide at https://www.zabbix.com/documentation...zabbix-agent-2, I am having an error.

The error that is popping up is:

```
c:\Users\<my-username>\Documents\zabbix-6.2.2\build\mingw>mingw32-make PCRE=c:\dev\pcre OPENSSL=c:\dev\openssl
windres.exe c:\Users\<my-username>\Documents\zabbix-6.2.2\build\mingw\..\..\build\win32\project\resource.rc  --input-format=rc -O coff --target=pe-x86-64 -D _WINDOWS -D ZABBIX_AGENT2 -o c:\Users\<my-username>\Documents\zabbix-6.2.2\build\mingw\..\..\src\go\cmd\zabbix_agent2\resource.syso
windres.exe: c:\\Users\\<my-username>\\Documents\\zabbix-6.2.2\\build\\mingw\\..\\..\\build\\win32\\project\\resource.rc:75: syntax error
  mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:188: c:\Users\<my-username>\Documents\zabbix-6.2.2\build\mingw\..\..\src\go\cmd\zabbix_agent2\resource.syso] Error 1
```

This appears to be a syntax error in the resource.rc file but after googling a bit a have no idea on how to fix the file.

If anyone can provide advice or help of any kind that would be much appreciated cause I am kind of stuck right now and can not move forward in my work cause of this compilation issue.

Thanks upfront to everyone !

Link of the resources I used:
I did a `git clone https://git.zabbix.com/scm/zbx/zabbix.git --branch 6.2.2 --depth 1 --single-branch zabbix-6.2.2` from this guide (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation...ilt_in_plugins)

Go: https://dl.google.com/go/go1.19.3.windows-amd64.msi
MniGW compiler: jztkft.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw-w64/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-win32/sjlj/x86_64-8.1.0-release-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0.7z

CMAKE: github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.23.5/cmake-3.23.5-windows-x86_64.msi

OpenSSL: netix.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-release/mingw-w64-v10.0.0.zip

PCRE: altushost-swe.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pcre/pcre/8.45/pcre-8.45.zip

I tried to switch to the zabbix 6.2 branch and editing the resource.rc file by removing everything from and below the line 75 that appears to be in error but I honestly don't really know what is wrong in the file or how to fix it at all.`